# AES decryption/ encryption implementation in C# - not using libraries

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to implement a **AES** system in **C#** to encrypt and decrypt messages using **AES**. The decrypted message of an encrypted message is different from the original text.

Where am I going wrong?

PS: I have included the **state.cs** class which contains the mixcolumns, subbytes and shiftrow methods as well as the inverse of these methods.

```
    private byte[] readHexString(string s)
        {
            int size = s.Length / 2;
            byte[] b = new byte[size];

            if ((size != 16) && (size != 24) && (size != 32))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                b[i] = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(2 * i, 2), 16);
            }
            return (b);
        }

        private byte[] readAsciiString(string s)
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[s.Length];
            b = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
            return (b);
        }

        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] inputKey = readHexString(tbKey.Text);
            Key key = new Key(inputKey);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("\nkey:\n" + key);

            byte[] inputPlain = readAsciiString(tbPlain.Text);
            State inputState = new State(inputPlain);

            Console.Out.WriteLine("state:\n" + inputState.ToMatrixString());

            //string outplain = ConvertHex(Encrypt(inputState, key));
            string  ciphertext = Encrypt(inputState, key);
            tbCiphertext.Text = ciphertext;


            byte[] inputPlain2 = readAsciiString(tbCiphertext.Text);
            State inputState2 = new State(inputPlain2);
            string plaintext = Decrypt(inputState2, key);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(plaintext);

        }

        private string Encrypt(State _inputState, Key k)
        {
            //string ciphertext;
            byte[] ciphertext;

            State thisState = _inputState;
            thisState = thisState.addRoundKey(k, 0);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(thisState.ToString());
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                thisState = thisState.subBytes();
                thisState = thisState.shiftRows();
                thisState = thisState.mixColumns();
                thisState = thisState.addRoundKey(k, i);
                Console.Out.WriteLine(thisState.ToString());
            }

            thisState = thisState.subBytes();
            thisState = thisState.shiftRows();
            thisState = thisState.addRoundKey(k, 10);

            Console.Out.WriteLine(thisState.ToString());

            ciphertext = readHexString(thisState.ToString());
            string output = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext.Length; i++)
            {
                output += ciphertext[i];
            }

            return ConvertHex(output);
        }

        public string Decrypt(State state, Key k)
        {
            byte[] plainText;
            State thisState = state.addRoundKey(k, 10); 
            thisState = thisState.shiftRowsInv();
            thisState = thisState.subBytesInv();


            for (int i = 9; i > 0; i--)
            {
                thisState = thisState.addRoundKey(k, i);
                thisState = thisState.mixColumnsInv();
                thisState = thisState.shiftRowsInv();
                thisState = thisState.subBytesInv();
             }
            thisState = thisState.addRoundKey(k, 0);
            plainText = readHexString(thisState.ToString());
             string output = "";
             for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
             {
                 output += plainText[i];
             }
             Console.Out.WriteLine(ConvertHex(output));
             return ConvertHex(output);

        }
        public string ConvertHex(String hexString)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i <= hexString.Length - 2; i += 2)
            {
                sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(Int32.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}


namespace Aes
{
    public class State
    {
        private const int nrofRow = 4;
        private const int nrofCol = 4;
        private byte[,] buf;
        //multiplication tables taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_mix_columns
        private static byte[] mul2 = {
            0x00,0x02,0x04,0x06,0x08,0x0a,0x0c,0x0e,0x10,0x12,0x14,0x16,0x18,0x1a,0x1c,0x1e,
            0x20,0x22,0x24,0x26,0x28,0x2a,0x2c,0x2e,0x30,0x32,0x34,0x36,0x38,0x3a,0x3c,0x3e,
            0x40,0x42,0x44,0x46,0x48,0x4a,0x4c,0x4e,0x50,0x52,0x54,0x56,0x58,0x5a,0x5c,0x5e,
            0x60,0x62,0x64,0x66,0x68,0x6a,0x6c,0x6e,0x70,0x72,0x74,0x76,0x78,0x7a,0x7c,0x7e,
            0x80,0x82,0x84,0x86,0x88,0x8a,0x8c,0x8e,0x90,0x92,0x94,0x96,0x98,0x9a,0x9c,0x9e,
            0xa0,0xa2,0xa4,0xa6,0xa8,0xaa,0xac,0xae,0xb0,0xb2,0xb4,0xb6,0xb8,0xba,0xbc,0xbe,
            0xc0,0xc2,0xc4,0xc6,0xc8,0xca,0xcc,0xce,0xd0,0xd2,0xd4,0xd6,0xd8,0xda,0xdc,0xde,
            0xe0,0xe2,0xe4,0xe6,0xe8,0xea,0xec,0xee,0xf0,0xf2,0xf4,0xf6,0xf8,0xfa,0xfc,0xfe,
            0x1b,0x19,0x1f,0x1d,0x13,0x11,0x17,0x15,0x0b,0x09,0x0f,0x0d,0x03,0x01,0x07,0x05,
            0x3b,0x39,0x3f,0x3d,0x33,0x31,0x37,0x35,0x2b,0x29,0x2f,0x2d,0x23,0x21,0x27,0x25,
            0x5b,0x59,0x5f,0x5d,0x53,0x51,0x57,0x55,0x4b,0x49,0x4f,0x4d,0x43,0x41,0x47,0x45,
            0x7b,0x79,0x7f,0x7d,0x73,0x71,0x77,0x75,0x6b,0x69,0x6f,0x6d,0x63,0x61,0x67,0x65,
            0x9b,0x99,0x9f,0x9d,0x93,0x91,0x97,0x95,0x8b,0x89,0x8f,0x8d,0x83,0x81,0x87,0x85,
            0xbb,0xb9,0xbf,0xbd,0xb3,0xb1,0xb7,0xb5,0xab,0xa9,0xaf,0xad,0xa3,0xa1,0xa7,0xa5,
            0xdb,0xd9,0xdf,0xdd,0xd3,0xd1,0xd7,0xd5,0xcb,0xc9,0xcf,0xcd,0xc3,0xc1,0xc7,0xc5,
            0xfb,0xf9,0xff,0xfd,0xf3,0xf1,0xf7,0xf5,0xeb,0xe9,0xef,0xed,0xe3,0xe1,0xe7,0xe5
        };

        private static byte[] mul3 = {
            0x00,0x03,0x06,0x05,0x0c,0x0f,0x0a,0x09,0x18,0x1b,0x1e,0x1d,0x14,0x17,0x12,0x11,
            0x30,0x33,0x36,0x35,0x3c,0x3f,0x3a,0x39,0x28,0x2b,0x2e,0x2d,0x24,0x27,0x22,0x21,
            0x60,0x63,0x66,0x65,0x6c,0x6f,0x6a,0x69,0x78,0x7b,0x7e,0x7d,0x74,0x77,0x72,0x71,
            0x50,0x53,0x56,0x55,0x5c,0x5f,0x5a,0x59,0x48,0x4b,0x4e,0x4d,0x44,0x47,0x42,0x41,
            0xc0,0xc3,0xc6,0xc5,0xcc,0xcf,0xca,0xc9,0xd8,0xdb,0xde,0xdd,0xd4,0xd7,0xd2,0xd1,
            0xf0,0xf3,0xf6,0xf5,0xfc,0xff,0xfa,0xf9,0xe8,0xeb,0xee,0xed,0xe4,0xe7,0xe2,0xe1,
            0xa0,0xa3,0xa6,0xa5,0xac,0xaf,0xaa,0xa9,0xb8,0xbb,0xbe,0xbd,0xb4,0xb7,0xb2,0xb1,
            0x90,0x93,0x96,0x95,0x9c,0x9f,0x9a,0x99,0x88,0x8b,0x8e,0x8d,0x84,0x87,0x82,0x81,
            0x9b,0x98,0x9d,0x9e,0x97,0x94,0x91,0x92,0x83,0x80,0x85,0x86,0x8f,0x8c,0x89,0x8a,
            0xab,0xa8,0xad,0xae,0xa7,0xa4,0xa1,0xa2,0xb3,0xb0,0xb5,0xb6,0xbf,0xbc,0xb9,0xba,
            0xfb,0xf8,0xfd,0xfe,0xf7,0xf4,0xf1,0xf2,0xe3,0xe0,0xe5,0xe6,0xef,0xec,0xe9,0xea,
            0xcb,0xc8,0xcd,0xce,0xc7,0xc4,0xc1,0xc2,0xd3,0xd0,0xd5,0xd6,0xdf,0xdc,0xd9,0xda,
            0x5b,0x58,0x5d,0x5e,0x57,0x54,0x51,0x52,0x43,0x40,0x45,0x46,0x4f,0x4c,0x49,0x4a,
            0x6b,0x68,0x6d,0x6e,0x67,0x64,0x61,0x62,0x73,0x70,0x75,0x76,0x7f,0x7c,0x79,0x7a,
            0x3b,0x38,0x3d,0x3e,0x37,0x34,0x31,0x32,0x23,0x20,0x25,0x26,0x2f,0x2c,0x29,0x2a,
            0x0b,0x08,0x0d,0x0e,0x07,0x04,0x01,0x02,0x13,0x10,0x15,0x16,0x1f,0x1c,0x19,0x1a
        };

        private static byte[] mul09 = {
            0x00,0x09,0x12,0x1b,0x24,0x2d,0x36,0x3f,0x48,0x41,0x5a,0x53,0x6c,0x65,0x7e,0x77,
            0x90,0x99,0x82,0x8b,0xb4,0xbd,0xa6,0xaf,0xd8,0xd1,0xca,0xc3,0xfc,0xf5,0xee,0xe7,
            0x3b,0x32,0x29,0x20,0x1f,0x16,0x0d,0x04,0x73,0x7a,0x61,0x68,0x57,0x5e,0x45,0x4c,
            0xab,0xa2,0xb9,0xb0,0x8f,0x86,0x9d,0x94,0xe3,0xea,0xf1,0xf8,0xc7,0xce,0xd5,0xdc,
            0x76,0x7f,0x64,0x6d,0x52,0x5b,0x40,0x49,0x3e,0x37,0x2c,0x25,0x1a,0x13,0x08,0x01,
            0xe6,0xef,0xf4,0xfd,0xc2,0xcb,0xd0,0xd9,0xae,0xa7,0xbc,0xb5,0x8a,0x83,0x98,0x91,
            0x4d,0x44,0x5f,0x56,0x69,0x60,0x7b,0x72,0x05,0x0c,0x17,0x1e,0x21,0x28,0x33,0x3a,
            0xdd,0xd4,0xcf,0xc6,0xf9,0xf0,0xeb,0xe2,0x95,0x9c,0x87,0x8e,0xb1,0xb8,0xa3,0xaa,
            0xec,0xe5,0xfe,0xf7,0xc8,0xc1,0xda,0xd3,0xa4,0xad,0xb6,0xbf,0x80,0x89,0x92,0x9b,
            0x7c,0x75,0x6e,0x67,0x58,0x51,0x4a,0x43,0x34,0x3d,0x26,0x2f,0x10,0x19,0x02,0x0b,
            0xd7,0xde,0xc5,0xcc,0xf3,0xfa,0xe1,0xe8,0x9f,0x96,0x8d,0x84,0xbb,0xb2,0xa9,0xa0,
            0x47,0x4e,0x55,0x5c,0x63,0x6a,0x71,0x78,0x0f,0x06,0x1d,0x14,0x2b,0x22,0x39,0x30,
            0x9a,0x93,0x88,0x81,0xbe,0xb7,0xac,0xa5,0xd2,0xdb,0xc0,0xc9,0xf6,0xff,0xe4,0xed,
            0x0a,0x03,0x18,0x11,0x2e,0x27,0x3c,0x35,0x42,0x4b,0x50,0x59,0x66,0x6f,0x74,0x7d,
            0xa1,0xa8,0xb3,0xba,0x85,0x8c,0x97,0x9e,0xe9,0xe0,0xfb,0xf2,0xcd,0xc4,0xdf,0xd6,
            0x31,0x38,0x23,0x2a,0x15,0x1c,0x07,0x0e,0x79,0x70,0x6b,0x62,0x5d,0x54,0x4f,0x46
        };

        private static byte[] mul11 = {
            0x00,0x0b,0x16,0x1d,0x2c,0x27,0x3a,0x31,0x58,0x53,0x4e,0x45,0x74,0x7f,0x62,0x69,
            0xb0,0xbb,0xa6,0xad,0x9c,0x97,0x8a,0x81,0xe8,0xe3,0xfe,0xf5,0xc4,0xcf,0xd2,0xd9,
            0x7b,0x70,0x6d,0x66,0x57,0x5c,0x41,0x4a,0x23,0x28,0x35,0x3e,0x0f,0x04,0x19,0x12,
            0xcb,0xc0,0xdd,0xd6,0xe7,0xec,0xf1,0xfa,0x93,0x98,0x85,0x8e,0xbf,0xb4,0xa9,0xa2,
            0xf6,0xfd,0xe0,0xeb,0xda,0xd1,0xcc,0xc7,0xae,0xa5,0xb8,0xb3,0x82,0x89,0x94,0x9f,
            0x46,0x4d,0x50,0x5b,0x6a,0x61,0x7c,0x77,0x1e,0x15,0x08,0x03,0x32,0x39,0x24,0x2f,
            0x8d,0x86,0x9b,0x90,0xa1,0xaa,0xb7,0xbc,0xd5,0xde,0xc3,0xc8,0xf9,0xf2,0xef,0xe4,
            0x3d,0x36,0x2b,0x20,0x11,0x1a,0x07,0x0c,0x65,0x6e,0x73,0x78,0x49,0x42,0x5f,0x54,
            0xf7,0xfc,0xe1,0xea,0xdb,0xd0,0xcd,0xc6,0xaf,0xa4,0xb9,0xb2,0x83,0x88,0x95,0x9e,
            0x47,0x4c,0x51,0x5a,0x6b,0x60,0x7d,0x76,0x1f,0x14,0x09,0x02,0x33,0x38,0x25,0x2e,
            0x8c,0x87,0x9a,0x91,0xa0,0xab,0xb6,0xbd,0xd4,0xdf,0xc2,0xc9,0xf8,0xf3,0xee,0xe5,
            0x3c,0x37,0x2a,0x21,0x10,0x1b,0x06,0x0d,0x64,0x6f,0x72,0x79,0x48,0x43,0x5e,0x55,
            0x01,0x0a,0x17,0x1c,0x2d,0x26,0x3b,0x30,0x59,0x52,0x4f,0x44,0x75,0x7e,0x63,0x68,
            0xb1,0xba,0xa7,0xac,0x9d,0x96,0x8b,0x80,0xe9,0xe2,0xff,0xf4,0xc5,0xce,0xd3,0xd8,
            0x7a,0x71,0x6c,0x67,0x56,0x5d,0x40,0x4b,0x22,0x29,0x34,0x3f,0x0e,0x05,0x18,0x13,
            0xca,0xc1,0xdc,0xd7,0xe6,0xed,0xf0,0xfb,0x92,0x99,0x84,0x8f,0xbe,0xb5,0xa8,0xa3
            };

        private static byte[] mul13 = {
            0x00,0x0d,0x1a,0x17,0x34,0x39,0x2e,0x23,0x68,0x65,0x72,0x7f,0x5c,0x51,0x46,0x4b,
            0xd0,0xdd,0xca,0xc7,0xe4,0xe9,0xfe,0xf3,0xb8,0xb5,0xa2,0xaf,0x8c,0x81,0x96,0x9b,
            0xbb,0xb6,0xa1,0xac,0x8f,0x82,0x95,0x98,0xd3,0xde,0xc9,0xc4,0xe7,0xea,0xfd,0xf0,
            0x6b,0x66,0x71,0x7c,0x5f,0x52,0x45,0x48,0x03,0x0e,0x19,0x14,0x37,0x3a,0x2d,0x20,
            0x6d,0x60,0x77,0x7a,0x59,0x54,0x43,0x4e,0x05,0x08,0x1f,0x12,0x31,0x3c,0x2b,0x26,
            0xbd,0xb0,0xa7,0xaa,0x89,0x84,0x93,0x9e,0xd5,0xd8,0xcf,0xc2,0xe1,0xec,0xfb,0xf6,
            0xd6,0xdb,0xcc,0xc1,0xe2,0xef,0xf8,0xf5,0xbe,0xb3,0xa4,0xa9,0x8a,0x87,0x90,0x9d,
            0x06,0x0b,0x1c,0x11,0x32,0x3f,0x28,0x25,0x6e,0x63,0x74,0x79,0x5a,0x57,0x40,0x4d,
            0xda,0xd7,0xc0,0xcd,0xee,0xe3,0xf4,0xf9,0xb2,0xbf,0xa8,0xa5,0x86,0x8b,0x9c,0x91,
            0x0a,0x07,0x10,0x1d,0x3e,0x33,0x24,0x29,0x62,0x6f,0x78,0x75,0x56,0x5b,0x4c,0x41,
            0x61,0x6c,0x7b,0x76,0x55,0x58,0x4f,0x42,0x09,0x04,0x13,0x1e,0x3d,0x30,0x27,0x2a,
            0xb1,0xbc,0xab,0xa6,0x85,0x88,0x9f,0x92,0xd9,0xd4,0xc3,0xce,0xed,0xe0,0xf7,0xfa,
            0xb7,0xba,0xad,0xa0,0x83,0x8e,0x99,0x94,0xdf,0xd2,0xc5,0xc8,0xeb,0xe6,0xf1,0xfc,
            0x67,0x6a,0x7d,0x70,0x53,0x5e,0x49,0x44,0x0f,0x02,0x15,0x18,0x3b,0x36,0x21,0x2c,
            0x0c,0x01,0x16,0x1b,0x38,0x35,0x22,0x2f,0x64,0x69,0x7e,0x73,0x50,0x5d,0x4a,0x47,
            0xdc,0xd1,0xc6,0xcb,0xe8,0xe5,0xf2,0xff,0xb4,0xb9,0xae,0xa3,0x80,0x8d,0x9a,0x97
        };

        private static byte[] mul14 = {
            0x00,0x0e,0x1c,0x12,0x38,0x36,0x24,0x2a,0x70,0x7e,0x6c,0x62,0x48,0x46,0x54,0x5a,
            0xe0,0xee,0xfc,0xf2,0xd8,0xd6,0xc4,0xca,0x90,0x9e,0x8c,0x82,0xa8,0xa6,0xb4,0xba,
            0xdb,0xd5,0xc7,0xc9,0xe3,0xed,0xff,0xf1,0xab,0xa5,0xb7,0xb9,0x93,0x9d,0x8f,0x81,
            0x3b,0x35,0x27,0x29,0x03,0x0d,0x1f,0x11,0x4b,0x45,0x57,0x59,0x73,0x7d,0x6f,0x61,
            0xad,0xa3,0xb1,0xbf,0x95,0x9b,0x89,0x87,0xdd,0xd3,0xc1,0xcf,0xe5,0xeb,0xf9,0xf7,
            0x4d,0x43,0x51,0x5f,0x75,0x7b,0x69,0x67,0x3d,0x33,0x21,0x2f,0x05,0x0b,0x19,0x17,
            0x76,0x78,0x6a,0x64,0x4e,0x40,0x52,0x5c,0x06,0x08,0x1a,0x14,0x3e,0x30,0x22,0x2c,
            0x96,0x98,0x8a,0x84,0xae,0xa0,0xb2,0xbc,0xe6,0xe8,0xfa,0xf4,0xde,0xd0,0xc2,0xcc,
            0x41,0x4f,0x5d,0x53,0x79,0x77,0x65,0x6b,0x31,0x3f,0x2d,0x23,0x09,0x07,0x15,0x1b,
            0xa1,0xaf,0xbd,0xb3,0x99,0x97,0x85,0x8b,0xd1,0xdf,0xcd,0xc3,0xe9,0xe7,0xf5,0xfb,
            0x9a,0x94,0x86,0x88,0xa2,0xac,0xbe,0xb0,0xea,0xe4,0xf6,0xf8,0xd2,0xdc,0xce,0xc0,
            0x7a,0x74,0x66,0x68,0x42,0x4c,0x5e,0x50,0x0a,0x04,0x16,0x18,0x32,0x3c,0x2e,0x20,
            0xec,0xe2,0xf0,0xfe,0xd4,0xda,0xc8,0xc6,0x9c,0x92,0x80,0x8e,0xa4,0xaa,0xb8,0xb6,
            0x0c,0x02,0x10,0x1e,0x34,0x3a,0x28,0x26,0x7c,0x72,0x60,0x6e,0x44,0x4a,0x58,0x56,
            0x37,0x39,0x2b,0x25,0x0f,0x01,0x13,0x1d,0x47,0x49,0x5b,0x55,0x7f,0x71,0x63,0x6d,
            0xd7,0xd9,0xcb,0xc5,0xef,0xe1,0xf3,0xfd,0xa7,0xa9,0xbb,0xb5,0x9f,0x91,0x83,0x8d
        };


        private State()
        {
            buf = new byte[nrofRow, nrofCol];
            for (int i = 0; i < nrofRow; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nrofCol; j++)
                {
                    buf[i, j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        public State(byte[] b)
        {
            buf = new byte[nrofRow, nrofCol];
            for (int i = 0; i < nrofRow; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nrofCol; j++)
                {
                    buf[i, j] = b[i + (nrofRow * j)];
                }
            }
        }

        public State subBytes()
        {
            State s = new State();

            for (int i = 0; i < nrofRow; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nrofCol; j++)
                {
                    s.buf[i, j] = Sbox.sbox[buf[i, j]];
                    //Console.Out.WriteLine("state[" + i + "," + j + "]=" + buf[i, j] + "--->" + s.buf[i, j]);
                }
            }
            return (s);
        }

        public State shiftRows()
        {
            State s = new State();

            for (int i = 0; i < nrofRow; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nrofCol; j++)
                {
                    s.buf[i, j] = buf[i, (i + j) % 4];
                    //Console.Out.WriteLine("state[" + i + "," + j + "]=" + s.buf[i, j]);
                }
            }
            return (s);
        }

        public State mixColumns()
        {
            State s = new State();
            for (int c = 0; c < nrofCol; c++)
            {
                s.buf[0, c] = (byte)(mul2[buf[0, c]] ^ mul3[buf[1, c]] ^ buf[2, c] ^ buf[3, c]);
                s.buf[1, c] = (byte)(buf[0, c] ^ mul2[buf[1, c]] ^ mul3[buf[2, c]] ^ buf[3, c]);
                s.buf[2, c] = (byte)(buf[0, c] ^ buf[1, c] ^ mul2[buf[2, c]] ^ mul3[buf[3, c]]);
                s.buf[3, c] = (byte)(mul3[buf[0, c]] ^ buf[1, c] ^ buf[2, c] ^ mul2[buf[3, c]]);
            }
            return (s);
        }

        public State subBytesInv()
        {
            // TODO
            State s = new State();
            for (int i = 0; i < nrofRow; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nrofCol; j++)
                {
                    s.buf[i, j] = Sbox.sboxInv[buf[i, j]];
                    //Console.Out.WriteLine("state[" + i + "," + j + "]=" + buf[i, j] + "--->" + s.buf[i, j]);
                }
            }
            return (s);
          }

        public State shiftRowsInv()
        {
            State s = new State();


            for (int i = 0; i < nrofRow; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nrofCol; j++)
                {
                    s.buf[i, j] = buf[i, (j - i + 4) % 4];
                    // Console.Out.WriteLine("state[" + i + "," + j + "]=" + s.buf[i, j]);
                }
            }
            return (s);
        }

        public State mixColumnsInv()
        {
            State s = new State();
            for (int c = 0; c < nrofCol; c++)
            {
                s.buf[0, c] = (byte)(mul14[buf[0, c]] ^ mul11[buf[1, c]] ^ mul13[buf[2, c]] ^ mul09[buf[3, c]]);
                s.buf[1, c] = (byte)(mul09[buf[0, c]] ^ mul14[buf[1, c]] ^ mul11[buf[2, c]] ^ mul13[buf[3, c]]);
                s.buf[2, c] = (byte)(mul13[buf[0, c]] ^ mul09[buf[1, c]] ^ mul14[buf[2, c]] ^ mul11[buf[3, c]]);
                s.buf[3, c] = (byte)(mul11[buf[0, c]] ^ mul13[buf[1, c]] ^ mul09[buf[2, c]] ^ mul14[buf[3, c]]);
            }
            return (s);
        }

        public State addRoundKey(Key key, int round)
        {
            State s = new State();
            for (int c = 0; c < nrofCol; c++)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < nrofRow; r++)
                {
                    s.buf[r, c] = (byte)(buf[r, c] ^ key.w[r, c + 4 * round]);
                    //Console.Out.WriteLine("state[" + r + "," + c + "]=" + buf[r, c] + " XOR " + key.w[r, c + 4 * round] + " = " + s.buf[r, c]);
                }
            }
            return (s);
        }

        public string ToMatrixString()
        {
            string s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < buf.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < buf.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    s += buf[i, j].ToString("X2") + " ";
                }
                s += "\n";
            }
            return (s);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < buf.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < buf.GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    s += buf[j, i].ToString("X2") + "";
                }
            }`enter code here`
            return (s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read about ["on-topic questions"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to help keep stack overflow a productive place for Q&A.  Specifically read the "why isn't my code working?" bullet point.

Comment: Home baking this seems unnecessary and possibly dangerous when AES is supported in the BCL

Comment: *"The decrypted message of an encrypted message is different from the original text."* - How is it different? Please provide example inputs and outputs. Also, this is quite a lot of code. You should debug it yourself to at least narrow down the search space to a single function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rather hard to check what is the mistake in your code, especially when some of your methods (especially in your `State`) are not available to check.

Here I can provide the AES128.cs code which I wrote myself and confirmed to be working. You can take a look and compare, especially on the intermediate methods like mixColumn, shiftRow, and sBox. People often got wrong there - including me as I coded.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Cryptography {
  public class AES128 {
    public const int BLOCK_SIZE = (128 / 8);
    public const int KEY_SIZE = (128 / 8);
    public const int ROUND_NO = 10;

    // forward sbox
    private readonly byte[] sBox = new byte[256] {
    //0     1    2      3     4    5     6     7      8    9     A      B    C     D     E     F
    0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76, //0
    0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0, //1
    0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15, //2
    0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75, //3
    0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84, //4
    0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf, //5
    0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8, //6
    0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2, //7
    0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73, //8
    0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb, //9
    0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79, //A
    0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08, //B
    0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a, //C
    0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e, //D
    0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf, //E
    0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16 }; //F


    private readonly byte[] inverseSBox = new byte[256] {
    //0     1    2      3     4    5     6     7      8    9     A      B    C     D     E     F
    0x52, 0x09, 0x6A, 0xD5, 0x30, 0x36, 0xA5, 0x38, 0xBF, 0x40, 0xA3, 0x9E, 0x81, 0xF3, 0xD7, 0xFB, //0
    0x7C, 0xE3, 0x39, 0x82, 0x9B, 0x2F, 0xFF, 0x87, 0x34, 0x8E, 0x43, 0x44, 0xC4, 0xDE, 0xE9, 0xCB, //1
    0x54, 0x7B, 0x94, 0x32, 0xA6, 0xC2, 0x23, 0x3D, 0xEE, 0x4C, 0x95, 0x0B, 0x42, 0xFA, 0xC3, 0x4E, //2
    0x08, 0x2E, 0xA1, 0x66, 0x28, 0xD9, 0x24, 0xB2, 0x76, 0x5B, 0xA2, 0x49, 0x6D, 0x8B, 0xD1, 0x25, //3
    0x72, 0xF8, 0xF6, 0x64, 0x86, 0x68, 0x98, 0x16, 0xD4, 0xA4, 0x5C, 0xCC, 0x5D, 0x65, 0xB6, 0x92, //4
    0x6C, 0x70, 0x48, 0x50, 0xFD, 0xED, 0xB9, 0xDA, 0x5E, 0x15, 0x46, 0x57, 0xA7, 0x8D, 0x9D, 0x84, //5
    0x90, 0xD8, 0xAB, 0x00, 0x8C, 0xBC, 0xD3, 0x0A, 0xF7, 0xE4, 0x58, 0x05, 0xB8, 0xB3, 0x45, 0x06, //6
    0xD0, 0x2C, 0x1E, 0x8F, 0xCA, 0x3F, 0x0F, 0x02, 0xC1, 0xAF, 0xBD, 0x03, 0x01, 0x13, 0x8A, 0x6B, //7
    0x3A, 0x91, 0x11, 0x41, 0x4F, 0x67, 0xDC, 0xEA, 0x97, 0xF2, 0xCF, 0xCE, 0xF0, 0xB4, 0xE6, 0x73, //8
    0x96, 0xAC, 0x74, 0x22, 0xE7, 0xAD, 0x35, 0x85, 0xE2, 0xF9, 0x37, 0xE8, 0x1C, 0x75, 0xDF, 0x6E, //9
    0x47, 0xF1, 0x1A, 0x71, 0x1D, 0x29, 0xC5, 0x89, 0x6F, 0xB7, 0x62, 0x0E, 0xAA, 0x18, 0xBE, 0x1B, //A
    0xFC, 0x56, 0x3E, 0x4B, 0xC6, 0xD2, 0x79, 0x20, 0x9A, 0xDB, 0xC0, 0xFE, 0x78, 0xCD, 0x5A, 0xF4, //B
    0x1F, 0xDD, 0xA8, 0x33, 0x88, 0x07, 0xC7, 0x31, 0xB1, 0x12, 0x10, 0x59, 0x27, 0x80, 0xEC, 0x5F, //C
    0x60, 0x51, 0x7F, 0xA9, 0x19, 0xB5, 0x4A, 0x0D, 0x2D, 0xE5, 0x7A, 0x9F, 0x93, 0xC9, 0x9C, 0xEF, //D
    0xA0, 0xE0, 0x3B, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x2A, 0xF5, 0xB0, 0xC8, 0xEB, 0xBB, 0x3C, 0x83, 0x53, 0x99, 0x61, //E
    0x17, 0x2B, 0x04, 0x7E, 0xBA, 0x77, 0xD6, 0x26, 0xE1, 0x69, 0x14, 0x63, 0x55, 0x21, 0x0C, 0x7D }; //F

    // round coefficients
    private readonly byte[] roundCoefficient = new byte[ROUND_NO] {
    0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1b, 0x36 }; //Round coefficient is 10, the number of key is 11

    // keys
    private byte[] key = new byte[KEY_SIZE] { 0x09, 0x15, 0x00, 0x97, 0x00, 0x12, 0x10, 0x13, 0x03, 0x02, 0x19, 0x02, 0x05, 0x00, 0x29, 0x80 };
    private byte[][] subkeys = new byte[ROUND_NO + 1][]; //each subkey is 16-bytes length
    public byte[] Key {
      get { return key; }
      set { //When key is set, subkeys are automatically generated
        if (value == null || value.Length != KEY_SIZE)
          return;
        key = value;        
        Array.Copy(key, subkeys[0], KEY_SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < ROUND_NO; ++i) {          
          Array.Copy(subkeys[i], subkeys[i + 1], KEY_SIZE);
          keyTransform(subkeys[i + 1], i);
        }
      }
    }

    public byte[][] Subkeys { get { return subkeys; } }

    public AES128(byte[] key = null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < ROUND_NO + 1; ++i)
        subkeys[i] = new byte[KEY_SIZE]; //All the necessary array size for this subkey is made at the beginning
      Key = key != null && key.Length == KEY_SIZE ? key : this.key; //key / default key
    }

    private void keywordTransform (ref byte[] keyword, int roundno) { //round no starts from 0, ends at 9
      if (roundno < 0 || roundno > ROUND_NO - 1)
        return;
      byte buf = keyword[0];
      keyword[0] = (byte)(sBox[keyword[1]] ^ roundCoefficient[roundno]);
      keyword[1] = sBox[keyword[2]];
      keyword[2] = sBox[keyword[3]];
      keyword[3] = sBox[buf];
    }

    private void keyTransform(byte[] key, int roundno) {
      byte[] keyword = new byte[4];
      Array.Copy(key, 12, keyword, 0, 4);
      keywordTransform(ref keyword, roundno);
      for (int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
        key[k] ^= keyword[k];
      for (int i = 0; i < KEY_SIZE - 4; ++i)
        key[i + 4] ^= key[i];
    }

    public const byte BYTE_POLY_REDUCTION = 0x1b;
    public const ushort POLY_REDUCTION = 0x11b;
    private void shiftRows(ref byte[] text) {
      byte buf;
      //shift row 2 (1 -> 13, 5 -> 1, 9 -> 5, 13 -> 9)
      buf = text[1];
      text[1] = text[5];
      text[5] = text[9];
      text[9] = text[13];
      text[13] = buf;

      //shift row 3 (2 -> 10, 6 -> 14, 10 -> 2, 14 -> 6)
      buf = text[2];
      text[2] = text[10];
      text[10] = buf;
      buf = text[6];
      text[6] = text[14];
      text[14] = buf;

      //shift row 4 (3 -> 7, 7 -> 11, 11 -> 15, 15 -> 3)
      buf = text[15];
      text[15] = text[11];
      text[11] = text[7];
      text[7] = text[3];
      text[3] = buf;
    }

    private void inverseShiftRows(ref byte[] text) {
      byte buf;
      //inverse shift row 2 (1 -> 5, 5 -> 9, 9 -> 13, 13 -> 1)
      buf = text[1];
      text[1] = text[13];
      text[13] = text[9];
      text[9] = text[5];
      text[5] = buf;

      //inverse shift row 3 (2 -> 10, 6 -> 14, 10 -> 2, 14 -> 6)
      buf = text[2];
      text[2] = text[10];
      text[10] = buf;
      buf = text[6];
      text[6] = text[14];
      text[14] = buf;

      //inverse shift row 4 (3 -> 15, 7 -> 3, 11 -> 7, 15 -> 11)
      buf = text[15];
      text[15] = text[3];
      text[3] = text[7];
      text[7] = text[11];
      text[11] = buf;
    }

    private byte galoisMult2(byte val, byte polyRed = BYTE_POLY_REDUCTION) { //used for GaloisMult with 2
      return val >= 128 ? (byte)((val << 1) ^ polyRed) : (byte)(val << 1);
    }

    private byte[] quickXORTable = new byte[8] { 0x00, 0x1b, 0x36, 0x2d, 0x6c, 0x77, 0x5a, 0x41 };
    private byte galoisDefaultMult(byte val, byte mult) {
      int buf = val << 3;
      if (mult != 0x0E)
        buf ^= val;
      if (mult > 0x0C)
        buf ^= val << 2;
      if ((mult & 0x02) > 0)
        buf ^= val << 1;
      byte xorval = quickXORTable[buf >> 8];
      return xorval == 0 ? (byte)buf : (byte)(buf ^ xorval);
    }

    private void mixColumn(ref byte[] text) {
      byte[] temp = new byte[4];
      int p;
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        p = i * 4;
        temp[0] = (byte)(galoisMult2(text[p]) ^ (galoisMult2(text[p + 1]) ^ text[p + 1]) ^ text[p + 2] ^ text[p + 3]);
        temp[1] = (byte)(galoisMult2(text[p + 1]) ^ (galoisMult2(text[p + 2]) ^ text[p + 2]) ^ text[p + 3] ^ text[p]);
        temp[2] = (byte)(galoisMult2(text[p + 2]) ^ (galoisMult2(text[p + 3]) ^ text[p + 3]) ^ text[p] ^ text[p + 1]);
        temp[3] = (byte)(galoisMult2(text[p + 3]) ^ (galoisMult2(text[p]) ^ text[p]) ^ text[p + 1] ^ text[p + 2]);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, text, p, 4);
      }
    }

    private byte[] inverseMixColumnMatrixElementTable = new byte[] { 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x09, 0x0E, 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x09 };
    private void inverseMixColumn(ref byte[] text) {
      byte[] temp = new byte[4];
      int p, p2;
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        p = i * 4;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
          p2 = 3 - j;
          temp[j] = (byte)(galoisDefaultMult(text[p], inverseMixColumnMatrixElementTable[p2]) ^ galoisDefaultMult(text[p + 1], inverseMixColumnMatrixElementTable[p2 + 1])
            ^ galoisDefaultMult(text[p + 2], inverseMixColumnMatrixElementTable[p2 + 2]) ^ galoisDefaultMult(text[p + 3], inverseMixColumnMatrixElementTable[p2 + 3]));
        }
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, text, p, 4);
      }
    }

    private void encryptBlock(byte[] plaintext, ref byte[] ciphertext) { //since this is private function, no "input protection" is needed.
      plaintext.CopyTo(ciphertext, 0);
      for (int j = 0; j < BLOCK_SIZE; ++j)
        ciphertext[j] ^= Subkeys[0][j];      
      for (int r = 0; r < ROUND_NO; ++r) {
        for (int i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; ++i)
          ciphertext[i] = sBox[ciphertext[i]];
        shiftRows(ref ciphertext);
        if (r < ROUND_NO - 1)
          mixColumn(ref ciphertext);
        for (int j = 0; j < AES128.BLOCK_SIZE; ++j)
          ciphertext[j] ^= Subkeys[r + 1][j];
      }
    }

    private void decryptBlock(byte[] ciphertext, ref byte[] plaintext) { //since this is private function, no "input protection" is needed.
      ciphertext.CopyTo(plaintext, 0);
      for (int r = 0; r < ROUND_NO; ++r) {
        for (int j = 0; j < BLOCK_SIZE; ++j)
          plaintext[j] ^= Subkeys[ROUND_NO - r][j];
        if (r > 0)
          inverseMixColumn(ref plaintext);
        inverseShiftRows(ref plaintext);
        for (int i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; ++i)
          plaintext[i] = inverseSBox[plaintext[i]];
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < BLOCK_SIZE; ++j)
        plaintext[j] ^= Subkeys[0][j];
    }

    public bool Encrypt(byte[] plaintext, ref byte[] ciphertext) {
      if (plaintext == null || ciphertext == null || ciphertext.Length < plaintext.Length) //invalid input(s)
        return false;
      int extrabytes = plaintext.Length % BLOCK_SIZE;
      int pblock = plaintext.Length / BLOCK_SIZE + (extrabytes > 0 ? 1 : 0);
      int cblock = ciphertext.Length / BLOCK_SIZE;
      if (cblock < pblock) //invalid size
        return false;
      pblock = plaintext.Length / BLOCK_SIZE;
      byte[] text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
      int p;
      for (int k = 0; k < pblock; ++k) { //Encrypt all possible blocks
        p = k * BLOCK_SIZE;
        Array.Copy(plaintext, p, text, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
        encryptBlock(text, ref text);
        Array.Copy(text, 0, ciphertext, p, BLOCK_SIZE);
      }
      if (extrabytes > 0) { //encrypt the left over
        p = pblock * BLOCK_SIZE;        
        Array.Copy(plaintext, p, text, 0, extrabytes);
        for (int i = extrabytes; i < BLOCK_SIZE; ++i) //TODO not sure if there is any faster way in C#
          text[i] = 0;
        encryptBlock(text, ref text);
        Array.Copy(text, 0, ciphertext, p, BLOCK_SIZE);
      }
      return true;
    }

    public bool Decrypt(byte[] ciphertext, ref byte[] plaintext) { //can only recover up to valid multiplication of 16, extra bytes are not decrypted
      if (plaintext == null || ciphertext == null) //invalid input(s)
        return false;      
      int cblock = ciphertext.Length / BLOCK_SIZE;
      int pblock = plaintext.Length / BLOCK_SIZE;
      if (pblock < cblock)
        return false; //invalid size
      byte[] text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
      int p;
      for (int k = 0; k < cblock; ++k) {
        p = k * BLOCK_SIZE;
        Array.Copy(ciphertext, p, text, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
        decryptBlock(text, ref text);
        Array.Copy(text, 0, plaintext, p, BLOCK_SIZE);
      } //extra bytes are not taken cared of...
      return true;
    }

  }
}
```

Note: the code is meant for 128-bit key

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked through the State.cs class and it seems all correct to me :/ Maybe the problem is with my Encrypt(), Decrypt() methods?
How can I attach the State.cs code?

Comment: Such complex case is best checked using **debug** mode and see the progress line by line to **pinpoint** where the error really is. Perhaps, you can update your question too by putting the *sample input* which gives you error (show this too!) then check if the same input gives the same error in my code. If it is not, then you can check your algorithm in debug mode one by one and then see in which line exactly the error started. To put additional codes to your comment, simply press little "edit" Label below the question. Put link if your code is in github,or simply paste the code in nice format

Comment: However, you start trying to debug the code with the mentioned way first and see if you can find where the mistake is.